# Java-after many iterations, why won't string variable hold full filename?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, file-upload, memory-leaks

Here's a brief outline of my Java code to upload archive files to a server. It's been working fine for a couple years. But it usually just uploads a small number of files at a time. Now it is needing to upload hundreds or thousands. And it is failing after a large-ish number of iterations.

```
public class BatchUploader implements Runnable {

    private int processUploads() {
        String myFilename;
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));
            try {
                while (!stopRunning && (myFilename = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (myFilename.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    myFile = FileHelper.getFileFromFullyQualifiedName(myFilename);
                    upload(myFile);
                }
            } finally {
                input.close();
                isUploading = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

After several hundred to several thousand uploads, I get an error like this:

```
02/20 23:17:05.314  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/baz (No such file or directory): java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
bk.a(SourceFile:41)
bk.d(SourceFile:123)
aU.e(SourceFile:181)
aU.run(SourceFile:24)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

The problem is that the string containing the path to the file (held in the String var myFilename) is truncated. Instead of `/home/baz` is should be `/home/bazillion/data/filename.arc`

Something seems to run out of memory in this loop. I have no idea what is going on. Can anyone give a suggestion?

Would it help to break out of the while-loop after a certain count, then resume after a few minutes?

To add insult to injury, the list of filenames to upload is wiped out after this exception. I'm sure there's an easy fix for that in my code, but I don't know what it is. I don't work in Java much.

Comment: Sounds like a problem in your input files. I'd validate them carefully.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown - I have validated them. I'm as sure as I can be that it is not a problem with the input files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's memory management; if it was, you'd get OutOfMemoryError; and in any case, it would not be truncated.

It would be interesting to look at `FileHelper.getFileFromFullyQualifiedName()`, the problem might very well be there. Or, maybe, in your data file?

> Would it help to break out of the while-loop after a certain count,  wthen resume after a few minutes?

Absolutely not. I'd make it an aggravated felony if it was up to me. We've got to program defensively: if you think you might have a bug, debug it, find the precise reason for it and fix it; don't brush it under the rug and then leave it to the poor maintenance programmer who'll be debugging a codebase 10,000 times as large ten years down the road at 3 am.

If your error is reproducible, add an "if" statement with string comparison, and print or log all variables to see what's really going on. Better yet, use a debugger, and set a conditional breakpoint there when the string begins with `/home/baz` and step through it examining all variables and seeing what happens.

To get a value visible after an exception is thrown, you can assign it to a field variable (the one defined just after the `public class ... {` line.

Good luck!

Comment: `FileHelper.getFileFromFullyQualifiedName()` is a very thin wrapper that just does `File file = new File(myFilename);`. I should not have used the wrapper in my example code because it is so thin it cannot be the problem here.

Comment: The problem is not the data file either. But I'm upvoting for the good ideas you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: It turned out to be a race condition.

Comment: Congratulations on successfully debugging a race conditions, these tends to be difficult! I am curious how it happened though, with String assignments being atomic, and no truncation happening in the code shown. Would be curious to hear more. Maybe a different thread was writing into the file as this one was reading?

Comment: Oh, I see now, the error stack is from a different thread not shown. BTW, it's a Java naming convention to name classes with first uppercase.

Comment: Yes, exactly. A different thread was writing into the file as this one was reading from it. Now I need to find the right way to implement file locking. Any suggestions? BTW, the names shown come from ProGuard.

Comment: New question about how to implement file locking: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21958636/463994

Comment: Since gave me so much extra reputation, I went ahead and answered your other question. Thank you!