# Java: how to synchronize file modification by threads

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, synchronization

Only one instance of my Java application can run at a time. It runs on Linux. I need to ensure that one thread doesn't modify the file while the other thread is using it.

I don't know which file locking or synchronization method to use. I have never done file locking in Java and I don't have much Java or programming experience.

I looked into java NIO and I read that "File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine." Right away I knew that I needed expert help because this is production code and I have almost no idea what I'm doing (and I have to get it done today).

Here's a brief outline of my code to upload some stuff (archive files) to a server. It gets the list of files to upload from a file (call it "listFile") -- and listFile can be modified while this method is reading from it. I minimize the chances of that by copying listFile to a temp file and using that temp file thereafter. But I think I need to lock the file during this copy process (or something like that).

```
package myPackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.example.my.FileHelper;
import com.example.my.Logger;

public class BatchUploader implements Runnable {

    private int processUploads() {
        File myFileToUpload;
        File copyOfListFile = null;
        try {
            copyOfListFile = new File("/path/to/temp/workfile");
            File origFile = new File("/path/to/listFile"); //"listFile" - the file that contains a list of files to upload
            DataWriter.copyFile(origFile, copyOfListFile);//see code below
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.log(ex);
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(copyOfListFile));
            try {
                while (!stopRunning && (fileToUploadName = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    upload(new File(fileToUploadName));
                }
            } finally {
                input.close();
                isUploading = false;
            }

        }
        return filesUploadedCount;
    }
}
```

Here is the code that modifies the list of files to be uploaded used in the above code:

```
public class DataWriter {

    public void modifyListOfFilesToUpload(String uploadedFilename) {

        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            File listOfFiles = new File("/path/to/listFile"); //file that contains a list of files to upload
            if (!listOfFiles.exists()) {
                //some code
            }

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listOfFiles));
            try {
                String line = "";
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (!line.isEmpty() && line.endsWith(FILE_EXTENSION)) {
                        if (!line.contains(uploadedFilename)) {
                            content.append(String.format("%1$s%n", line));
                        } else {
                            //some code
                        }
                    } else {
                        //some code
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                input.close();
            }
            this.write("/path/to/", "listFile", content.toString(), false, false, false);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.debug("Error reading/writing uploads logfile: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void copyFile(File in, File out) throws IOException {
        FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(in).getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(out).getChannel();
        try {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (inChannel != null) {
                inChannel.close();
            }
            if (outChannel != null) {
                outChannel.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void write(String path, String fileName, String data, boolean append, boolean addNewLine, boolean doLog) {
        try {
            File file = FileHelper.getFile(fileName, path);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, append));
            bw.write(data);
            if (addNewLine) {
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            if (doLog) {
                Logger.debug(String.format("Wrote %1$s%2$s", path, fileName));
            }
        } catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
            Logger.log(ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me which file you're trying to lock. If you're trying to lock the temp file, I don't understand why. If you're trying to lock the list file, I'm also not sure why (though I have more ideas). I'm also curious why you are creating a temp version of a file in a non-dynamic location while using a dynamic object (the thread). That seems to me like its asking for trouble. Can you make your copy outside of the thread?

Comment: @Avery I am thinking that I should lock the "listFile" so it isn't modified while copying it. I need to copy the "listFile" every time my thread enters this method. I don't know about non-dynamic locations. And I don't know if I am asking for trouble... but that's why I posted my question ;-)

Comment: @Avery would a dynamic location be one that had, for example, a random or GUID-based file name?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way to do that. Another possible solution, depending on the size of listFile, is to simply copy it into memory, though this may be prohibitive if the file is anywhere near large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My I suggest a slightly different approach. Afair on Linux the file rename (mv) operation is atomic on local disks. No chance for one process to see a 'half written' file.

Let XXX be a sequence number with three (or more) digits. You could let your DataWriter append to a file called listFile-XXX.prepare and write a fixed number N of filenames into it. When N names are written, close the file and rename it (atomic, see above) to listFile-XXX. With the next filename, start writing to listFile-YYY where YYY=XXX+1.

Your BatchUploader may at any time check whether it finds files matching the pattern listFile-XXX, open them, read them upload the named files, close and delete them. There is no chance for the threads to mess up each other's file.

Implementation hints:

1. Make sure to use a polling mechanism in BatchUploader that waits 1 or more seconds if it does not find a file ready for upload (prevent idle wait).
2. You may want to make sure to sort the listFile-XXX according to XXX to make sure the uploading is kept in sequence.
3. Of course you could variate the protocol of when listFile-XXX.prepare is closed. If DataWriter has nothing to do for a longer time, you don't want to have files ready for upload hang around just because there are not yet N ready.

Benefits: no locking (which will be a pain to get right), no copying, easy overview over the work queue and it state in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different suggestion. Assuming your file names don't have '\n' characters in them (it's a big assumption on linux, I know, but you can have your writer look up for that), why not only read complete lines and ignore the incomplete ones? By incomplete lines, I mean lines that end with EOF and not with \n.

Edit: see more suggestions in comments below.

Comment: Hi. When examining the file, there are no incomplete lines. The incomplete lines only exist transiently if two threads are accessing the file (reading/writing) at the same time. However, your suggestion might actually work. It isn't a solution to the threading problem, but knowing the code, I see that it probably would work. However, I'm working on fixing this the right way, but I have also now included a check for incomplete lines -- just because such a check is a good idea. :-)

Comment: Hi. Your goal is to ignore the transient lines, right? You know a line is transient if it does not end with '\n'. I think it's a fairly clean approach, often used in software protocols (think xOn/xOff). The writer writes a bunch, and then sends a message meaning "I am done for now", then the reader reads a bunch. Your \n is just such a message. However, if you are interested in learning how to implement atomicity in Unix (useful for more generic cases, such as random file access for example), that's an interesting thing to learn, too.

Comment: BTW, this is probably elsewhere in the code, but I don't see where your file is deleted. With such large throughput, you probably want to delete some lines or the entire file at some point. Also, what happens when the program crashes and then restarts? By then, some files are uploaded, and some are not.. how do you know which is which? Also, I wonder why the threads communicate via a file, and not directly by sending each other messages through a queue or some other mechanism.

Comment: Another possible mechanism to consider, depending on your circumstances, might be for the 'writer' to move the individual files into the "uploadMe" directory, and for the reader, to upload and then erase files from that directory. Moving files under Linux is very fast.

Comment: Thank you for all your good ideas. However, I can't move the files. I would have to copy, which might introduce race conditions. I think I have a solution for today -- at least a temporary solution using synchronized blocks -- but I plan to keep working on this over the next few weeks using the ideas suggested here. I will try to report back on the final results. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record: you can copy, *then* move/rename. Then the move would be atomic. Not advocating this solution at all or saying it's better than yours, just pointing it out.

Comment: Of course, copying, unlike renaming, seems overly expensive.